# Problema nell'importare un file CSS esterno in una pagina HTML

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I state that I am new to the world of HTML and CSS. I am creating this page to customize the 404 error on Altervista which is called not_found.html, which imports the styles to customize it from an external file called Style.css. the CSS file in question is located in a folder called Sheets-Style while the page is positioned directly in the root of the space that Altervista makes available.

the code I wrote is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Errore - 404</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Media/Icona.png" type="image/png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Fogli-Stile/Style.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>OOPS... Qualcosa &egrave; andato storto.</h1>
      <p>
        Purtroppo non siamo riusciti a trovare quello che stavi cercando.
        <br/>
        Prova a tornare alla Home e a vedere se trovi qualcosa che ti interessa.
        <br/>
        Oppure facci sapere come possiamo migliorarci.
        <br/>
      </p>
      <button class="BTN_action" onclick="location.href='index.php'">
        Torna alla Home
      </button>
      <button class="BTN_action">
        Inviami un suggerimento
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that doing so when I open the page from Chrome I don't import the css file and therefore the styles I had chosen don't appear.

Does anyone by any chance know where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not in English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am understanding, your CSS path might be wrong. Try this :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Fogli-Stile/Style.css"/>
```

If this doesn't work then you need to share the structure of the files.